# Как правильно воспользоваться методом, создающим кнопку, находящимся в другом python-модуле?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt, qpushbutton

Мне показалось, что будет лучше, если я отделю некоторые графические составляющие от основного кода. Поэтому решил сделать класс в новом python-модуле, который будет содержать функции, создающие графические элементы с нужными мне характеристиками.

Для начала в файле **Design.py** создал класс `UIClass()`, в котором находится метод `create_button()`, создающий простую кнопку. 
Этим методом хочу воспользоваться в файле с основным кодом - **Main.py**. 
Делаю это я неправильно, из-за чего возникает такая ошибка:

> QLayout: Cannot add a null widget to QVBoxLayout

Я понимаю, что делаю очень глупую ошибку, но даже не знаю, как гуглить такой вопрос. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как поправить код?

**Design.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class UIClass:
    def create_button(self):
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Кнопка")
```

**Main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import Design


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Design.UIClass()
        self.button1 = self.ui.create_button()
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.button1)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Вы создали кнопку, но забыли выпустить в мир (return ...): `self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Кнопка") return self.button`.

Ошибка не глупая - просто недосмотр, такое с каждым может случиться

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у меня возникает идея вынести в отдельное место создание какого-либо виджета
и не важно где он находится, в основном модуле или нет (если нет - делаем импорт),
, например пусть это будет `кнопка`.

Я бы предложил при создании класса наследоваться от `QPushButton` 
и передал бы все необходимые параметры, которые мне нужны в том или ином случае.

Попробуйте:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
import random

class PushButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text, color, parent=None):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(text, parent)
        self.setText(text)
        self.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: {color.name()}; font: bold 20px;")
        self.clicked.connect(lambda: print(self.text()))


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        for i in range(3):
            self.button = PushButton(
                                     f'Button {i}', 
                                     QtGui.QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3)), 
                                     self
            )
            vbox.addWidget(self.button)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо!